# How to set bean property from composite attribute?

Tags: jsf-2, attributes, composite-component, backing-beans

I'm trying to set a backing bean property when using a composite component (the backing bean is a composite `attribute`).

There is a bean property (ex, `finalDraft`) that I want to conditionally fill with the attribute (conditionally, because the attribute is not required).

The backing bean:

```
class Bean ... {
   String finalDraft; // getters+setters

   @PostConstruct
   void init() {
       String draftAttr = (...) getAttributes("draft");
       if(draftAttr!=null) {
           finalDraft = draftAttr;
       }
   }
}
```

The composite:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="bean" required="true" ... />
    <composite:attribute name="draft" type="java.lang.String" />
</composite:interface>
```

So far I tried with the `getAttributes("draft")` within the `@PostConstruct` of `bean`, but it resolves to null (notes: view-scope).

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't bind your bean to your composite component. Pass the property directly instead:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:body>
        <composite:interface>
            <composite:attribute name="showDraft" default="true" />
            <composite:attribute name="draft" />
        </composite:interface>
        <composite:implementation>
            <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.draft}" 
                rendered="#{cc.attrs.showDraft}" />
        </composite:implementation>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Then you'll be able to use it in your main page either:

```
<comp:draftInput value="#{bean.finalDraft}" />
```

or

```
<comp:draftInput showDraft="false" />
```

I'm afraid you're confused about the backing bean here. One thing is what you have in your current `@ViewScoped` bean and the other is the composite component. The composite knows nothing about current view's managed bean, it only receives parameters and displays them. It might be a single facelet view or also might have a class in his back, which **knows only about the composite** and nothing about scopes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In my use case the `draft` attribute is not a `boolean` but a `String` that is to be used in a text component (much like a default value of an `inputText` component). The `input`'s value is binded to a bean property (`bean.finalText` which I decided to ommit because I just want to access the `draft` attribute in the backing bean). My problem was, in case of draft existing,  I wasn't able to set the finalText with the draft text

Comment: I already solved it by calling `f:event` and explicitly calling the setter I wanted (and respective argument, which in my case is `draft`)

Comment: @nuno, still don't understand why are you filling a bean property with a composite attribute when it loads. Don't you already have that attribute in your bean?

Comment: I decided to set the bean property on the composite-component render because I do some in-place validations, and the bean is actually a super-class - the implementation of the bean varies according to the command given. Anyway, I solved with `<f:event type="javax.faces.event.PreRenderComponentEvent" listener="#{cc.attrs.bean.setFinalText(cc.attrs.draft)}" />`